# Is a functional positive on a dense set bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Assume we have a functional $f$ defined on a $C^*$-algebra $A$. I know that there is a proper dense subset $D\subset A$ such that for every positive element $a\in D$ we have $f(a)\ge 0$.

> Can we conclude that $f$ is bounded on $A$?

Comment: Which kind of functional is f? Linear, multiplicative, compatible with *???

Comment: In general only linear.

Comment: Definitely an interesting question! Perhaps one can construct a functional which is positive ONLY on a dense subset? At first glance, such a functional shouldn't be continuous, right?

Comment: I realized I can also assume that $A$ is until and the identity belongs to $D$.

Comment: how did you get that?

Comment: Besides, since the functional is only linear, the unit isn't so important...

Comment: On the other hand, it might help along the way, ie for statements about positive elements...tough question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $A=C[0,1]\oplus C[0,1]$, and let 
$$
D=\{(a,b):\ a,b\in C[0,1],\ \text{Im}\, a\ne0,\ \text{Im}\,b\ne0\}\cup\{(1,0)\}. 
$$
Let $\psi$ be an unbounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$. Define 
$$
\phi(a,b)=\psi(b).
$$
Then $\phi$ is positive on $D$ (because $\phi(1,0)=0$, and $(1,0)$ is the only positive element of $D$), and it is not bounded.

Comment: +1 for the elegance and simplicity of your counterexample!